# IntlDateFormatter returns wrong date

Tags: php, date

I'm having trouble formatting a specific date using the IntlDateFormatter class. I have used various methods, all to no avail, and my current code this:

```
$dataForma  = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1451420082));
// output > $dataForma string(26) "2015-12-29 18:14:42.000000"

$dateFormater = \IntlDateFormatter::create(
'pt_br',
\IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
\IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
'America/Sao_Paulo',
\IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
'Y.MM MMM.d');

$dateFormater->format($dataForma);
// output > string(14) "2016.12 dez.29"
```

My code is configured as follows:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese-brazil");
```

What am I letting go?